# AS2 Accessing instance names in for loop with numbers at the end

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

so right now here is my code

```
var binaryArray:Array = [
                     1,0,0,
                     0,1,0,
                     0,0,1]

for(i = 0; i < binaryArray.length; i++){
    if(binaryArray[i] == 1){
        light + i.gotoAndStop(2);
    }
}
```

I have 9 movieclips on stage with the instances of light0, light1, light2, etc...

But I can't seem to get this to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that light0, light1, etc are on the stage you need to go:

```
this["light" + i.toString()].gotoAndStop(2);
```